# Undefined index: name

Tags: php, css, html

I keep getting the following message when loading the form:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: name in **C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php** on line **267**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: email in **C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php** on line **275**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: message in **C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php** on line **281**

I've looked and followed a number of examples to fix this issue but for some reason I can't seem to find the solution. Any ideas?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'enquiry'; 
    $to = 'dgdrd@live.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from Visitor';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">We will get in tocuh soon.</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Error! Try again later.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="main.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name ="name" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                <?php $errName=''; echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email1">email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name ="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
                <?php $errEmail=''; echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">comment</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                <?php $errMessage=''; echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-wrapper">Send</button>

    <hr>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php $result=''; echo $result; ?>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2):

It basically tell you your `$_POST` doesn't contain whatever key you getting error. You can give some check before getting value from `$_POST`

```
$name = (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : "" ;
```

It basically check wether the `$_POST['name']` is empty or not. For extra information use PHPMailer to send mail, if not you will get some trouble such as your mail always send to spam etc.

Comment: // Check if name has been entered after this line you already create a $name variable why you still using $_POST['name']? Try to replace it with $name.

Comment: Like this:   // Check if name has been entered
  if (!$name) {
   $errName = 'Please enter your name';
  }

Comment: Could you update your html code? I think error is on your html side

Comment: No problems. Added.

Comment: Replace your html code with $name as well you did saw the error is in line 267 right? Find out which is the line, I bet is the line in your html code. When you first open up your web page $_POST is surely not being set that is the problem you getting that error. I assume after you submit once your app the error gone. If you really wan to get rid of the error you need create all the variable outside your if(isset($_POST["submit"])) statement as empty varaible $name = ""; Otherwise even you replace your html code with $name it told u undifined variable $name.

Comment: @ffxdean after solve your problem you dissapear. Well done bro

Comment: No the problem still isn't solved. I tried your solution but I am still getting the same error message. Line 267 is in the HTML code.